# How to import SSH public key to Ubuntu

Tags: ssh

I have received a public key as a `xxx.pub` file via email and am supposed to import it onto an Ubuntu machine so that the other side can access it without a password. I have already created a user through which this should happen.

Now to my question: How and where do I have to import this `xxx.pub` file? Do I have to give the user any rights? Or assign to that. I didn't get the hang of the instructions as they only explain how to generate a key pair. But in my case is the public key already available.

Comment: As the user that should be able to log in, append the public key to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, e.g. with `cat xxx.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. If the directory `.ssh` does not exist yet, you can either create it manually or generate a key pair with `ssh-keygen` which will create this directory and the key files.

Comment: "cat xxx.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"   thanks, that worked!

Comment: I wrote my comment as an answer and edited your question a bit. If you like you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the user that should be able to log in, append the public key to the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, e.g. with

```
cat xxx.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

If the directory `.ssh` does not exist yet, you can either create it manually or use `ssh-keygen` to generate a key pair which will create this directory and the key files.

See also https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-use-ssh-public-key-authentication/

If the authentication without password does not work after adding the public key, check the permissions, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-a-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically